# What happend if preempt_enable() inside an nmi?

Tags: kernel, panic, nmi

https://gitlab.com/redhat/centos-stream/src/kernel/centos-stream-8/-/blob/ccf40dfacd314ab0fea16cfc6f4eded1a08e2710/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c#L1331

`preempt_enable()` before `nmi_exit()`, is this a OK code?

```
    if ((m.cs & 3) == 3) {
        /* If this triggers there is no way to recover. Die hard. */
        BUG_ON(!on_thread_stack() || !user_mode(regs));
        local_irq_enable();
        preempt_enable();

        current->task_struct_rh->mce_ripv = !!(m.mcgstatus & MCG_STATUS_RIPV);
        current->task_struct_rh->mce_whole_page = whole_page(&m);

        if (kill_it || do_memory_failure(&m))
            force_sig(SIGBUS, current);
        preempt_disable();
        local_irq_disable();
    } else {
        if (!fixup_exception(regs, X86_TRAP_MC))
            mce_panic("Failed kernel mode recovery", &m, NULL);
    }

out_ist:
    nmi_exit();
}
```

In my understanding, the kernel can't preempt if `preempt_count > 0`, in this case, it is inside NMI, so `preempt_count > 0`.

It is sending SIGBUS:

```
force_sig(SIGBUS, current);
```

seems unnecessary to do `local_irq_enable` and `preempt_enable`?